# Derivation of formulas (2) and (11) in S S Wilks Recurrence of Extreme Observations, 1958

Tags: probability-theory

The article is here: http://journals.cambridge.org/download.php?file=%2FJAZ%2FJAZ1_01%2FS144678870002512Xa.pdf&code=2b38e4500b319a4a3f42f347c677729f

I'm interested in derivation of formulas (2) and (11).

Now, when it comes to formula (2), I have a slight problem with understanding intuitively what probability element is. Despite this, I think this is derived as follows. We need to find the probability of random variable $y$ having arbitrary value. Since it has continuous distribution and $F_y(t) = P(y \leq t) = P(x_1\leq t,\ldots,x_m\leq t) = F_x^m(t)$, we have
$$
dP = mF^{m-1}dF.
$$
So basically "probability element" that is mentioned just before formula (2) is $dP$. Is it correct?

Now to formula (11). Here we have $F_y(t) = \binom{m}{r}P(x_1\leq t,\ldots,x_{m-r}\leq t,x_{m-r+1}>t,\ldots,x_m>t)=\binom{m}{r}F_x^{m-r}(t)[1-F_x(t)]^r$. Now, using the similar logic used for derivation of (2), the probability element must be
$$
dP = \binom{m}{r}\{(m-r)F^{m-r-1}(1-F)^r-rF^{m-r}(1-F)^{r-1}\}dF.
$$
Simplifying what's inside the curly brackets, we have
$$
F^{m-r-1}(1-F)^{r-1}\{(m-r)(1-F)-rF\}=F^{m-r-1}(1-F)^{r-1}\{m(1-F)-r\}.
$$
When you plug this into the formula for $dP$, the only way you can arrive at formula (11) in the article is if what's inside the curly brackets in the last formula is
$$
m(1-F)-r \equiv rF,
$$
which is not the case. Where am I mistaken?

Thanks. And happy new year.

Comment: For formula (2), they've defined $F$ to be the cumulative distribution function. This is made more clear by the condition $0 \le F \le 1$. Note that $\frac{d}{dF} F^m = mF^{m-1}$, so permitting some abuse of notation, we would have $dF^m = mF^{m-1}dF$. So your intuition is correct.

Comment: Thanks. Could you look into how formula (11) is derived? You can start from the beginning of the chapter formula (11) belongs to really. I mean no need to waste time on going through whole chapter 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble with your approach is that $$F_y(t) \ne \binom{m}{r}P(x_1\leqslant t,\ldots,x_{m-r}\leqslant t,x_{m-r+1}>t,\ldots,x_m>t)=\binom{m}{r}F_x^{m-r}(t)[1-F_x(t)]^r.$$ A post hoc way to see that the identity in your post is impossible is that the RHS goes to zero when $t\to\infty$ hence it cannot be a CDF.

To get the correct identity, consider the ordered sample $(x_{(k)})$, then $F_y(t)=P(x_{(m-r)}\leqslant t)$ and the RHS of the identity in your post is $P(x_{(m-r)}\leqslant t\lt x_{(m-r+1)})=P(x_{(m-r)}\leqslant t)-P(x_{(m-r+1)}\leqslant t)$ hence $$F_y(t)=\sum_{s=0}^r\binom{m}{s}P(x_1\leqslant t,\ldots,x_{m-s}\leqslant t,x_{m-s+1}>t,\ldots,x_m>t),$$ that is, $$F_y(t)=\sum_{s=0}^r\binom{m}{s}F_x^{m-s}(t)[1-F_x(t)]^s.$$ Differentiating carefully the RHS yields (11).

Comment: Oh, stupid me! Thank you very much. How could I not have seen that for $y\leq t$ you don't necessarily need precisely $r$ values in the sample to be $>$ than $t$, and that it suffices to require no more than $r$ sample values are $>t$?..